# How to make a boolean toggle using JPQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpql

I have a list of sessions that are available to purchase. After a customer purchases a session how do I change the `available` field to `0` or `false` so that they no longer appear in the list?

Here is my Session entity class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
    
@Column(name="date")
private String date;
    
@Column(name="time")
private String time;
    
@Column(name="available")
private boolean available;
    
@Column(name="side")
private String side;
```

Here is my Query that i'm trying to use:

```
// Only update the available field while leaving everything else alone. Use the 
// Modifying annotation when using UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE Queries

@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("UPDATE Session s SET s.available=0")
List<Session>updateStatusNotAvailable(Boolean notAvailable);
```

Comment: After a lot of research I have come to the conclusion that you cannot get an entity by the id and use a JPQL query to update one of the fields. I have discovered that you if you get an entity by its id that you can change every other entity in the table except for the one that you are updating. Im not sure why it works that way but it does.

Answer (score 1):

Add `Transactional` annotation on update query:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("UPDATE Session s SET s.available = false")
List<Session> updateStatusNotAvailable();
```

While calling above method:

```
List<Session> sessions = sessionRepository.updateStatusNotAvailable();
```

Comment: Thank you for your input but it still failed to work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set your variable in your case "notAvailable", you have to inject your variable into Query annotation. There are two examples:

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("UPDATE Session s SET s.available=?1")
List<Session>updateStatusNotAvailable(Boolean notAvailable);
```

Path param example:

```
// path param example
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("UPDATE Session s SET s.available=:notAvailable")
List<Session>updateStatusNotAvailable(@Param("notAvailable") Boolean notAvailable);
```

Comment: Thank you for you input, I greatly appreciate it! Unfortunately those two methods did not work. I received a "QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations" error from both of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass Session Id for which you want to set availability as `false`.

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("UPDATE Session s SET s.available=false where s.id=:id")
List<Session>updateStatusNotAvailable(Long id);
```